# Replacing list bullets with images for different categories

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have been using list bullets `<li>` for my website. I have a few icons and wanted to know how could I use images in place of the bullets for the content specific tag/category? I have a section where users can post content under several different categories - eat/drink, play, other, listen/watch, and explore. I wanted to show a icon for each specific category when the content is being displayed.

Can someone please give me an example of this so I can implement it for my website? Thank you!

View:

```
<% for letsgo in @letsgos %>

  <li>
    <%= letsgo_icon(letsgo) %>
    <b>Let's Go...<span class="content"><%= letsgo.content %></span></b>
      <% if current_user?(letsgo.user) %>
        <%= link_to "delete", letsgo, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" }%> 
      <% end %> 
      <% unless current_user?(letsgo.user) %> 
        <%= link_to "I'm Interested", interested_letsgo_path(letsgo), method: :message %> | 
        <%= link_to "repost", repost_letsgo_path(letsgo), method: :post %>
      <% end %>

  <% end %>

</li>
```

Letsgohelper.rb:

```
module LetsgoHelper
  def letsgo_icon_class(letsgo)
    case letsgo.tag
    when "Eat/Drink"
      "fork27.png"
    when "Play"
      "play48.png"
    when "Listen/Watch"
      "entry.png"
    when "Explore"
      "binoculars18.png"
    when "Other"
      "calendar146.png"
  end
end

  def letsgo_icon(letsgo)
    content_tag(:span, "", class: letsgo_icon_class(letsgo) )
  end
end
```

Comment: use background-image instead...

Comment: The code posted is not HTML, and it has no apparent relevance to the question.

Answer (score 5):

You can disable the bullets using the `list-style-type: none` [css rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) and then use a `background-image` css style on the list item, or include a span (or some other element) inside the list item which would display the icon.

Something like this:

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;  
}

.icon-play,
.icon-eat
{
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
   background-repeat: none;   
}

.icon-play
{
   background-color: #f08080;
   /* use a background image here */
}

.icon-eat
{
   background-color: #80f080;
   /* use a background image here */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="icon-play"></span> Let's Play</li>
  <li><span class="icon-eat"></span> Let's Eat</li>
</ul>
```

And the css rules:

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.icon-play {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url(Img/wmd-buttons.png?v=581875b1c136);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip. I will have to find out how to tell it to detect which icon to show for the specific category.

Comment: You could also apply this to pseudo elements `<li class="image-eat">Let's Eat</li>` and the CSS `li:before { content: ''; display: inline-block; width: 5px; height: 5px; } .image-eat:before { background: url(); }`

Comment: I edited the original post with current code. I figured I needed to create a helper method that maps the string on the tag to the correct CSS class. If you could show me how should I adjust your CSS example to fit?